# Replace a string starting with a word until two new line characters

Tags: python

I am new to regex in python and am trying to replace a substring inside a string. My substring starts with a specific word and ends with two new line characters.

Below is what I tried

```
import re
a=re.sub(r'Report from.+', r' ', 'To: abcd@gef.org;     Report from xxxxx \n     Category\t Score\t  \n xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxt  \n xxxxxxx\t xxxxxxx\t \n\n original message\n')
```

Output:

```
To: abcd@gef.org;      
     Category    Score    
 xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxt  
 xxxxxxx     xxxxxxx     

 original message
```

Expected Output:

```
To: abcd@gef.org;      
 original message
```

I also tried:

```
re.sub(r'Report from.+\n', r' ', 'To: abcd@gef.org;     Report from xxxxx \n     Category\t Score\t  \n xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxt  \n xxxxxxx\t xxxxxxx\t \n\n original message\n')
```

but it wasn't even matching "Report from" literal.

I think I am half-way there. Can anyone please help?

Edit: I want to replace everything that starts with "Report from" all the way until the first occurrence of two new-line characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `?` to mark the 'end' of the substring you wish to replace.

```
import re

text = 'To: abcd@gef.org;     Report from xxxxx \n     Category\t Score\t  \n xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxt  \n xxxxxxx\t xxxxxxx\t \n\n original message\n'

a=re.sub(r'Report from.+?\n\n', r'\n', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

```
print(a)
```

```
To: abcd@gef.org;     
 original message
```

Comment: That worked fine on some of the texts. But for some of the texts it replaced everything until the last occurrence of \n\n (two new-line characters). I want to replace the string only until the first occurrence of two new line characters

Comment: @pysparker Then you'll need a lazy operator `?`, will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much for the solution! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a simple state machine to do this.  You have two states: you are looking for the first line in a block, or you are in a block and looking for the blank line.  ("Two consecutive newlines" is the same as "I see a blank line when I read through the file line by line".)

```
import enum from Enum, auto

class LookFor(Enum):
  REPORT = auto()
  BLANK = auto()

state = LookFor.REPORT
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if state == LookFor.REPORT:
      print(line, end='')
      if line.startswith('Report from'):
        state = LookFor.BLANK
    elif state == LookFor.BLANK:
      if line == '\n':
        print(line, end='')
        state = LookFor.TO
```

The specific code I've written makes some assumptions about what you're looking for, and in particular that you *can* iterate through it line-by-line; you could adapt this to make more complex decisions about what state to switch to or add additional states as suited your application.